# Django: creating a model from a raw sql query that performs a Join on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, django

So I have a mysql database that we use for reporting. We are trying to create an API that queries this database in order to find clients that deposit over a certain ammount:

query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.`LOGIN`,SUM(t.PROFIT) AS total_deposits,u.`phone` 
FROM mt4_trades t join mt4_users u on t.LOGIN = u.LOGIN
where t.CMD=6 and t.COMMENT like 'DP%' 
and u.`group` like 'FX%'
group by t.`LOGIN`
having sum(t.PROFIT)>10000;
```

I performed **python manage.py inspectdb** in order to create a model with those fields. The problem is those fields are coming from different tables.

This is what my model looks like:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BigDeposit(models.Model):
    login = models.IntegerField(db_column='LOGIN', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    group = models.CharField(db_column='GROUP', max_length=16)  # Field name made lowercase.
    profit = models.FloatField(db_column='PROFIT')  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone = models.CharField(db_column='PHONE', max_length=32)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '?????'
```

1st question: what am I supposed to put in the db_table field in such a case.

2nd question: how can I perform a raw query to create a 'BigDeposit' queryset from this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want a single model? If those fields are coming from separate tables, why don't you create models for those tables and do a join/aggregate when you need to?

Comment: So basically make 2 models and perform an equivalent of the mysql query using django ORM?

Comment: Yes, why not? If you have Trade and User models, with a foreign key between them, your query ends up being something like `Trade.objects.values_list('login', 'user__phone').filter(cmd=6, comment__startswith='DP', user__group__startswith='FX').annotate(profit_sum=Sum('profit')).filter(profit_sum__gte=10000)`.

Comment: The thing is those tables are much bigger  and have a lot more fields that are also related to other tables. Should I create the 2 models using all the fields from the table? or should I just include the fields I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, why not? If you have Trade and User models, with a foreign key
>   between them, your query ends up being something like
>   Trade.objects.values_list('login', 'user__phone').filter(cmd=6,
>   comment__startswith='DP',
>   user__group__startswith='FX').annotate(profit_sum=Sum('profit')).filter(profit_sum__gte=10000).

That worked! thanks!